# Generics class type constraints?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Suppose I have the following code :

```
sealed class Animal(val type: String) {
  data class Cat(val color: String) : Animal("cat")
  data class Dog(val mood: String , val ownersName : String) : Animal("dog")
}

abstract class AnimalDescriptor<out T : Animal>(val a: T) {
  abstract fun getSummary(): String
}

class CatDescriptor(a: Animal.Cat) : AnimalDescriptor<Animal.Cat>(a) {
  override fun getSummary(): String {
     return "The color of this ${a.type} is ${a.color}"
  }
}

class DogDescriptor(a : Animal.Dog) : AnimalDescriptor<Animal.Dog>(a) {
  override fun getSummary(): String {
    return "${a.ownersName}'s ${a.type} is ${a.mood}"
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  fun summary(a : Animal) : String {
    return when(a) {
      is Animal.Cat -> CatDescriptor(a)
      is Animal.Dog -> DogDescriptor(a)
    }.getSummary()
  }

  val kitten = Animal.Cat("yellow")
  val doggy = Animal.Dog("happy" , "John")

  println(summary(kitten))
  println(summary(doggy))
}
```

The output is :

```
The color of this cat is yellow
John's dog is happy
```

It indeed is what I want .

But I feel a little ‘fishy’ , because the duplicated type declaration in the initialization of `AnimalDescriptor` :

```
class CatDescriptor(a: Animal.Cat) : AnimalDescriptor<Animal.Cat>(a)
```

Moreover , it cannot forbid us writing this class :

```
class ADescriptor(a : Animal) : AnimalDescriptor<Animal>(a) {
  override fun getSummary(): String {
    return "type = ${a.type} "
  }
}
```

Which is meaningless in this scenario.

Is there a better design ?

Functional style or even Kategory incorporation is welcome.

**But at least preserve the `sealed class` design.**

[KotlinConf 2017](https://youtu.be/s9oMED6ZikQ?t=1279)  This slide caught my eyeballs :

[image]
[image: It blows my mind]

I am not sure if pure Kotlin (means without other 3rd library) can achieve my requirement , but it seems with Kategory it somehow can do this , is it possible in Kategory ? how ?

-----  updated reply to @PaulHicks -----

`AnimalDescriptor` is inevitable if I want to do some `template` inside , such as :

```
abstract class AnimalDescriptor<out T : Animal>(val a: T) {
  fun sayHello() : String {
    return "Hello : " + getSummary()
  }
  abstract fun getSummary(): String
}


  fun hello(a: Animal): String {
    return when (a) {
      is Animal.Cat -> CatDescriptor(a)
      is Animal.Dog -> DogDescriptor(a)
    }.sayHello()
  }

  val kitten = Animal.Cat("yellow")
  val doggy = Animal.Dog("happy", "John")

  println(hello(kitten))
  println(hello(doggy))
```

And , it outputs :

```
Hello : The color of this cat is yellow
Hello : John's dog is happy
```

Comment: The example may be confusing me; is the question specifically about classes with formal parameters matching constructor parameters? In your example code, I'd recommend simply dropping the formal parameter from `AnimalDescriptor` since it adds nothing, but that may be avoiding the point of your question?

Comment: Hi , @PaulHicks , `AnimalDescriptor` is inevitable if I want to do some String template . Please see my updated question.

Comment: So the (valid and good) unpretty code is because of a design choice: you have two mirroring class hierarchies. This is a reasonable design choice but not the only one. Either or both hierarchy can be broken/reworked in order to avoid the unprettiness. You can decide if inheritance is more valuable than terseness and composability (leave the code as-is) or if one of the alternative designs would be better.

Comment: The first alternative design that pops into my head would be to get rid of AnimalDescriptor entirely. Assuming `getSummary` is the only reason for AnimalDescriptor, then replace that class hierarchy with extension properties or functions.